# PHP: echo shell_exec("cat ".$filename." | head -1"); causes cat: write error: Broken pipe error

Tags: php, shell, command-line-interface

```
$php index2.php testphp

$filename = $argv[1];

echo shell_exec("cat ".$filename." | head -1");
```

causes the following error:

```
cat: write error: Broken pipe error
```

I do not know why I am getting this error. Changing to the following still gives me the error:

```
echo shell_exec("cat testphp | head -1");
```

Comment: Just a side note, but you _really_ should be using `escapeshellarg()` on the filename. Not only to prevent shell-code injection attacks, but also to ensure that normal filenames doesn't create havoc on your code.

Comment: In addition to what @ChristianF has said, you should consider using PHP directly to get the first line of the file. Note that like most other tools, `head` is capable of reading a file by itself, so no need for a pipe here either way.

Comment: @TomFenech changing the code so there is no pipe and just using head to read the file fixes the issue thanks. If you want to post an answer I can accept it.

Comment: The way I would recommend reading the first line of your file is by using `fopen`, then `fgets`, then `fclose` in PHP, although it's not really a direct answer to your question. I'm glad you got it working anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot say for certain why you are getting the broken pipe error. I tested the code on my system, and it worked just fine.

However, the better solution in this case is probably just to use PHP instead of going through third party programs. Getting the first line of a file is trivial with `file()` and some simple array manipulation:

```
$data = file ($filename);
if (is_array ($data)) {
    echo "Error reading file!";
    return 1;
}

echo $data[0];
```

If the file is too big to contain in memory at once, then you can use `fopen()` and `fread()` to read one line at a time. Just remember to add checks around the functions, to handle the error conditions that might occur.